# What is this bolt called?

Tags: suspension, axle, fatbike, bolt

[image]

It's part of my front axle and I need another one like this to keep the wheel on. Links to where I could buy one would be appreciated too.

The bike is a fatbike with suspension.

Bolt threads into this barrel which looks the same on both ends which becomes the axle. The screw itself is m10x1.25 with a fat allen key insert.

[image]

Comment: It would help to know the brand of the bike and the components on it.

Comment: hmm yes, more detail required, it's not a part that's super common, so details on wheel and fork brands, or photos of the other parts would help.

Comment: It apparently would be called an "end cap", but that does you little good, since the style you have is fairly "odd".

Comment: It's close to a [low-head cap screw](https://www.pts-uk.com/products/socket-screws/low-head-socket-cap-screws) or even an ultra-low-head, but I'd be wary of recommending a generic fastener to hold the front wheel on, at least without further information (though to be honest that looks almost like black-anodised aluminium, which would suggest the screw itself isn't  not load bearing

Comment: no, the screw itself is not load-bearing, it's to hold the axle in place as well as with fork pinch bolts, that's it

Comment: @James I thought as much, but I've had the head snap off an ultra low-head screw unexpectedly (on a handlebar phone mount when I hit a pothole, so a smaller screw but a smaller load).  Then your axle would be much less constrained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for "Large head socket screw" gets close, but no cigar.
Also try 'cap screw'.

You need to know the thread, of course.

You may be able to replace it with a (rounded) socket button screw, eg. https://www.kayfast.co.uk/category/517/Socket-Screws

**Update:** Search *Socket Pipe Plug*, also described as *Flange Plug* and *Blanking Plug* - these look very similar:
https://www.accu.co.uk/en/flat-head-socket-pipe-plugs/177868-HPPF-M10-1-A4-BL

Or: *Slotted blanking screw* eg. https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/NiceCNC-Billet-Mirror-Hole-Blanking-Plugs-M10x1-25-Aluminum-Motorcycle-Universal-/303185376819 - interesting that these are also available with a left-hand thread.

You need not (necessarily) be wedded to the allen socket - an ordinary M10 bolt over the end, perhaps with a suitable washer, might suffice, for quick replacement.

Comment: Socket pipe plug seems exactly what it is lol. I got a M10x1.25 hex bolt, did the same job. now I know what is is called.

Answer (score 0):

The bolts and the tube in the picture comprise the part called your *front thru-axle.*

The way the world currently works is that thru-axles for the most part are supplied by fork and frame manufacturers. They have to match the fork/frame in terms of overall length, threaded length, thread pitch, and interface of the bolt head (some are countersunk, and flat-shouldered ones have to have enough space). The bolt itself isn't a generic part.

The order of operations I recommend here would be:

1. Email the fork manufacturer if it's a suspension fork or the bike manufacturer if not and see if they can help you out. The hope here is that in a lot of cases, companies have warranty departments that sometimes just have stuff like this and can drop it in the mail. They may ask you to go through a dealer. Include the picture you took in the email as well as full info about the bike (model, serial number.)
2. If that's unsuccessful you're probably looking at trying to get a whole new axle. There are other questions on here about how to size them. It's off a suspension fork and generally speaking fork manufacturers all sell replacement thru axles for their forks.
3. Just using a hex cap screw and a big washer is very likely fine, but there's a degree of at-your-own-risk-ness because it's more or less the most safety critical fastener on the bike.